# How can I make my input to be only limited to a maximum of 10 numbers and don't allow any characters?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to be able to put a maximum length for the phone number entered and don't allow any characters too. However, with the format below it does limit the person to enter 10 characters but it also allows any other character to be added too.

Now if I change `type` to `type="number"` maxLength will not work and also characters such as [minus(-) or plus(+)] will still go through.

How can I make my input to be only limited to a maximum of 10 numbers and don't allow any characters?

```
<input
  placeholder="Telephone Number"
  className="input_fields telephone_no"
  type="tel"
  maxLength={"10"}
  name="phoneNumber"
  id="teacher_telephone_no"
  value={this.state.user.phoneNumber}
  onChange={e =>
    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    })
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` to test your input before setting the state, as:

```
     <input
        placeholder="Telephone Number"
        className="input_fields telephone_no"
        type="tel"
        maxLength={"10"}
        name="phoneNumber"
        id="teacher_telephone_no"
        value={user}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (/^[0-9]{1,10}$/.test(e.target.value)) {
             this.setState({
               user: {
               ...this.state.user,
               [e.target.name]: e.target.value
               }
            })
          }
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression and `keyup` event to prevent symbol from typing .

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input')
input.onkeyup = function() {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d]/, "")

}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Telephone Number" className="input_fields telephone_no" type="tel" maxLength={ "10"} name="phoneNumber" id="teacher_telephone_no" />
```

Comment: unfortunately the pattern attribute does not work

Comment: @marksmith, I could suggest you are a way to use regular expresion, will you feel ok to do that?

Comment: Sure, what is your suggestion?

Comment: @marksmith, update the code, Check if it works!